# Partially default initialize template template parameters with internal type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-templates

```
template <template <typename> class container_type>
class MyClass
{
    class Internal{
    };
};
```

I want to use this class (or how it would look correctly) in a way like the following...

```
MyClass(std::list);
```

...so that in MyClass `container_type` is declared/`typedef`'d as:

```
std::list<Internal*>
```

Is something like this somehow possible?

Comment: What do you have against Stroustrup indentation style...?

Comment: it's hard to visually match up opening closing braces

Comment: @greatwolf You generally do not edit based on programming style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want something like the following:

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>

template <template <typename, typename> 
          class Container = std::list>
class MyClass 
{
    class Internal
    { };

    Container<Internal*, std::allocator<Internal*>> my_list;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<> m;
}
```

[Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e1a0ce7fa4d654f) a compilable example you can play with. Note that both the extra `typename` and the definition of an allocator is required here.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out to also make it work with variadic templates wich eliminates the need of specifying the allocator. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5298a9dd13faa97